# placement new of temporary vairable

Tags: c++, new-operator

I'm currently learning the STL and finding something I cant understand in the placement new;

placement new put a temporary varieable into a allocated memory.

But the life of temporary clearly says that the temporary varieable should be died after the line;

Why is that work?

```
    // construct method to set value into some already allocated
    template <class T, class T2>
    inline void construct(T* pointer, T2& value)
    {
        new(pointer) T(value);
    }
```

Comment: "placement new put a temporary varieable into a allocated memory" - that assertion is wrong. All this does is construct a copy of `value` into the memory pointed to by `pointer`. There is nothing 'temporary' here to expire. (well, besides the return result of the placement-new expression, but that's just `pointer`).

Comment: @WhozCraig isn't T(value) is to creat a temporary varieable?

Comment: For a similar reason to why `new T(value)` doesn't create a temporary `T` object

Comment: @Artyer sorry I totally lost, I originally think the temporary object is created without name,  and the life scope is so short, as long as run after the line they die. If I ject new a object without name it, isn't it a temporary object?

Comment: Non-placement `new` creates objects whose lifetimes extend until they are `delete`d.

Comment: `T(value)` only creates a temporary when it is a *postfix-expression*, not when it is part of a *new-expression*.  Subtle detail of the C++ grammar.